# ping failed error in connection testing(om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure)

Tags: java

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using hibernate.

I'm testing the connection using this :

[image]

Comment: Is MySQL running on localhost? On port 3306? What does `netstat -an` tell you?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup     http://postimg.org/image/hjlvrmmc5/

Comment: Right... You're trying to connect to SQLServer with a MySQL JDBC URL. That won't work...

Comment: may be this will help you: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/tutorials/sdeecorm.jsp

Comment: I can't see result of netstat -an [I use proxy at the moment] but Andres is right... if you try to connect to SQLServer with a MySQL JDBC URL - that's will not work :)

Comment: @grep I want to connect MySQL, how to connect , am basically Android developer, am not good in java

Answer (score 0):

From the image supplied in comments, I can see that you're running an MS SQLServer, and you're trying to connect using a MySQL JDBC URL.

Instead, your JDBC URL should be of the form (see [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx) for further info)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=test
```

And of course you need the SQL Server drivers ([MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) or [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)), instead of the MySQL drivers.

Cheers,

Comment: how to connect MySQL JDBC,

Comment: in order to connect to MYSQL server, you must install it. :)